# Take child node value via lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq

I want to take value from `name` node and `fix` node using a lambda expression.

```
<Issue>
  <name>asdasasdasd</name>
  <fix>zxcczxczxczzxc </fix>
</Issue>
```

My try was

```
GlobalVariables.issuesList = doc.Descendants("Issue").Select(s => new IssueModel(s.Value, s.Value) { }).AsEnumerable();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is far from clear, but I suspect you *may* want something like:

```
// I would strongly discourage you from using global variables...
var issues = doc.Descendants("Issue")
                .Select(x => new IssueModel((string) x.Element("name"),
                                            (string) x.Element("fix")))
                .ToList();
```

The `ToList()` call will force immediate evaluation of the query; without it, it would be reevaluated every time you iterate over `issues`.

Note that if the `name` or `fix` element is missing from an `Issue`, with the code above you'll get a null reference instead. You could instead use `x.Element("name").Value` (and ditto for `fix`) in which case you'll get an exception immediately if the element is missing.

Comment: Thank you, It worked. We are using enumerable because in that XML, only issue node and fix node tag is there.

Comment: @Vecto7: It's not clear what you mean by "we are using enumerable" - but it sounds like maybe you're okay using the explicit conversion to `string` rather than the `Value` property, if that's what you meant...

Comment: In that XML file there are 50 issue and fix node,So I used AsEnumerable() instead of list

Comment: @Vecto7: That sounds like a non-sequitur to me. What benefit do you think you'll get? It's not like 50 objects represents a significant memory hit...

Comment: @Vecto7: And even if you want to use lazy evaluation, you don't need to call AsEnumerable.